# How to handle multi users in Symfony 2?

Tags: php, symfony

I would like to handle differents users in Symfony2.
I use FOSUserBundle to manage my users, but i can't define different types (e.g : a normal user and a pro user).
How can i succed it ?

Comment: Why not have usertype and differentiate the users ?

Comment: Because i would like to store different informations in function of my user type (so i'll need two registration forms, profile form, etc ...)

Comment: No.. why two registration.. ? You will differentiate users only by `usertype`

Comment: For example in my pro registration i will have **name, phone number, company's name ...**and in user registration **mail, picture, ...**

Comment: Ah, For Pro User Registration you should have a hidden field like usertype, And in the controller, you should see that whether the usertype parameter comes in the post,, if so then you should put usertype as 1 else  usertype is 0 .. The usertype 1 is for pro users

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use some discriminator field on user entity that will represent user's type. And according to its value you can use different forms for editing users.

For simplifying that process you can use [Single Table Inheritance](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/inheritance-mapping.html#single-table-inheritance) pattern. You will have different entities for different values of discriminator column. It is convenient if you have not so many unique fields in each entity.

Also if you have many other fields related to specific user type in addition to your User's fields I would recommend you to use [Class Table Inheritance](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/inheritance-mapping.html#class-table-inheritance). In that case you will also have different entities for different user types but you will have optimized (in storage side) tables in database.